# Getting Error "app.UseBlazor" for "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have got an error on Configure method startup.cs file.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Pets API V1");
    });

    **app.UseBlazor<PetsApp.Program>();**
}
```

Error: An item with the same key has already been added

Can anyone assist me?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `app.UseBlazor<PetsApp.Program>();` Run the program. How often does the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: Usually this kind of error is because you're trying to add a duplicated key to a dictionary somewhere. Mind sharing the complete stack tracing?

Comment: only one time get into breakpoint and got the error

Comment: @mjwills
this is .net core project (version 2.2.0.*) and integrate blazor document framework into this project 
but once I run project then got this error into startup.cs class.

Comment: Awesome - please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The Blazor 0.7 does not work with .NET Core 2.2 and will not work on it, since team working on it concentrate on the RazorComponents which will be part of .Net Core 3.0. You should run application under .Net Core 2.1 if you want use Blazor 0.7

You should copy UseBlazor method to your codebase and do small modifications, to fix the issue

```
namespace BlazorHelper
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Mime;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
    using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods for registration related to Blazor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is almost full rip-off of
    /// https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server/Builder/BlazorApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs
    /// </remarks>
    public static class BlazorExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the middleware pipeline to work with Blazor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TProgram">Any type from the client app project. This is used to identify the client app assembly.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="app">The <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/> with configured Blazor.</returns>
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseLocalBlazor<TProgram>(
            this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            var clientAssemblyInServerBinDir = typeof(TProgram).Assembly;
            return app.UseLocalBlazor(new BlazorOptions
            {
                ClientAssemblyPath = clientAssemblyInServerBinDir.Location,
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the middleware pipeline to work with Blazor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">The <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/>.</param>
        /// <param name="options">Options to configure the middleware.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/> with configured Blazor.</returns>
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseLocalBlazor(
            this IApplicationBuilder app,
            BlazorOptions options)
        {
            // TODO: Make the .blazor.config file contents sane
            // Currently the items in it are bizarre and don't relate to their purpose,
            // hence all the path manipulation here. We shouldn't be hardcoding 'dist' here either.
            var env = (IHostingEnvironment)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IHostingEnvironment));
            var config = BlazorConfig.Read(options.ClientAssemblyPath);

            // First, match the request against files in the client app dist directory
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(config.DistPath),
                ContentTypeProvider = CreateContentTypeProvider(config.EnableDebugging),
                OnPrepareResponse = SetCacheHeaders
            });

            // * Before publishing, we serve the wwwroot files directly from source
            //   (and don't require them to be copied into dist).
            //   In this case, WebRootPath will be nonempty if that directory exists.
            // * After publishing, the wwwroot files are already copied to 'dist' and
            //   will be served by the above middleware, so we do nothing here.
            //   In this case, WebRootPath will be empty (the publish process sets this).
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.WebRootPath))
            {
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(config.WebRootPath),
                    OnPrepareResponse = SetCacheHeaders
                });
            }

            // Accept debugger connections
            if (config.EnableDebugging)
            {
                // Disable MonoDebugProxy, since it require me to maintain copy of Blazor code
                // app.UseMonoDebugProxy();
            }

            // Finally, use SPA fallback routing (serve default page for anything else,
            // excluding /_framework/*)
            app.MapWhen(IsNotFrameworkDir, childAppBuilder =>
            {
                var indexHtmlPath = FindIndexHtmlFile(config);
                var indexHtmlStaticFileOptions = string.IsNullOrEmpty(indexHtmlPath)
                    ? null : new StaticFileOptions
                    {
                        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.GetDirectoryName(indexHtmlPath)),
                        OnPrepareResponse = SetCacheHeaders
                    };

                childAppBuilder.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = indexHtmlStaticFileOptions;
                });
            });

            return app;
        }

        private static string FindIndexHtmlFile(BlazorConfig config)
        {
            // Before publishing, the client project may have a wwwroot directory.
            // If so, and if it contains index.html, use that.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.WebRootPath))
            {
                var wwwrootIndexHtmlPath = Path.Combine(config.WebRootPath, "index.html");
                if (File.Exists(wwwrootIndexHtmlPath))
                {
                    return wwwrootIndexHtmlPath;
                }
            }

            // After publishing, the client project won't have a wwwroot directory.
            // The contents from that dir will have been copied to "dist" during publish.
            // So if "dist/index.html" now exists, use that.
            var distIndexHtmlPath = Path.Combine(config.DistPath, "index.html");
            if (File.Exists(distIndexHtmlPath))
            {
                return distIndexHtmlPath;
            }

            // Since there's no index.html, we'll use the default DefaultPageStaticFileOptions,
            // hence we'll look for index.html in the host server app's wwwroot.
            return null;
        }

        private static void SetCacheHeaders(StaticFileResponseContext ctx)
        {
            // By setting "Cache-Control: no-cache", we're allowing the browser to store
            // a cached copy of the response, but telling it that it must check with the
            // server for modifications (based on Etag) before using that cached copy.
            // Longer term, we should generate URLs based on content hashes (at least
            // for published apps) so that the browser doesn't need to make any requests
            // for unchanged files.
            var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
            if (headers.CacheControl == null)
            {
                headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                {
                    NoCache = true
                };
            }
        }

        private static bool IsNotFrameworkDir(HttpContext context)
            => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/_framework");

        private static IContentTypeProvider CreateContentTypeProvider(bool enableDebugging)
        {
            var result = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            result.Mappings.Add(".dll", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            result.Mappings.Add(".mem", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

            if (enableDebugging)
            {
                result.Mappings.Add(".pdb", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            }

            return result;
        }

        internal class BlazorConfig
        {
            private BlazorConfig(string assemblyPath)
            {
                // TODO: Instead of assuming the lines are in a specific order, either JSON-encode
                // the whole thing, or at least give the lines key prefixes (e.g., "reload:<someuri>")
                // so we're not dependent on order and all lines being present.
                var configFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(assemblyPath, ".blazor.config");
                var configLines = File.ReadLines(configFilePath).ToList();
                this.SourceMSBuildPath = configLines[0];

                if (this.SourceMSBuildPath == ".")
                {
                    this.SourceMSBuildPath = assemblyPath;
                }

                var sourceMsBuildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.SourceMSBuildPath);
                this.SourceOutputAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(sourceMsBuildDir, configLines[1]);

                var webRootPath = Path.Combine(sourceMsBuildDir, "wwwroot");
                if (Directory.Exists(webRootPath))
                {
                    this.WebRootPath = webRootPath;
                }

                this.EnableDebugging = configLines.Contains("debug:true", StringComparer.Ordinal);
            }

            public string SourceMSBuildPath { get; }

            public string SourceOutputAssemblyPath { get; }

            public string WebRootPath { get; }

            public string DistPath
                => Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.SourceOutputAssemblyPath), "dist");

            public bool EnableDebugging { get; }

            public static BlazorConfig Read(string assemblyPath)
                => new BlazorConfig(assemblyPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Use this insted of standard 'UseBlazor'
app.UseLocalBlazor<BlazorApp.Program>();
```

Comment: Thank you @codevision
This is working perfect for me